# Change position on td in table

Tags: html, css

I am making website for my school and I am stuck in a table lol :/. I am making schedule and I want to add buttons for Friday and Sunday and I am making it in table for better items layer :D . This is my code and can I make it like this: http://prntscr.com/b2s8oa

Now its like this: http://prntscr.com/b2s8wx

**Code:**

```
<div class="rasporedden">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="sliki/levostrelka.png" class="rasporedstrelka">
      </td>
      <td>
        Понеделник
      </td>

      <td>
        Вторник
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="sliki/desnostrelka.png" class="rasporedstrelka">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `table { width: 100% }` ?

Comment: Now this is happening http://prntscr.com/b2si51

Comment: nvm my fault. but its not 100% good :3 Look at this http://prntscr.com/b2sizu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS, give the first and last cells a width equal to the width of the image they contain by using the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). Doing so should force the rest of the cells to dynamically fill the remaining space.

Here's a quick example:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;}
table{
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:100%
}
td:first-child,td:last-child{
  background:#ddd;
  text-align:center;
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>«</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>dolor sit amet</td>
    <td>»</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Having said that, though, unless a table makes semantic sense for the data you are presenting, it's not the best option for laying out content.

Answer (score 0):

This should set you off in the right direction.

```css
.rasporedden table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.left-align {
  text-align: left;
}
.right-align {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="rasporedden">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="left-align">
        <img src="sliki/levostrelka.png" class="rasporedstrelka">
        left
      </td>
      <td>
        Понеделник
      </td>

      <td>
        Вторник
      </td>
      <td class="right-align">
        right
        <img src="sliki/desnostrelka.png" class="rasporedstrelka">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```